# formatBytes32String not working in ethers v6

Tags: javascript, ethers.js

```js
const ethers =  require('ethers');

async function createBytes (args) {
   const name = args[0];
   const bytes = ethers.utils.formatBytes32String(name);
   console.log('name: ',bytes)
}

createBytes(process.argv.slice(2));
```

[image]

What's wrong in it and i can't understand this error. I am trying to run js file through a powershell

Comment: `ether.utils` is `undefined`.

Answer (score 8):

You are using the old `v5` syntax.

`formatBytes32String` has been renamed to `encodeBytes32String` in `v6`:

```
// v5:
bytes32 = ethers.utils.formatBytes32String(text)
text = ethers.utils.parseBytes32String(bytes32)

// v6:
bytes32 = ethers.encodeBytes32String(text)
text = ethers.decodeBytes32String(bytes32)
```

---

Change your code to the following:

```js
const ethers =  require('ethers');

 async function createBytes (args) {
    const name = args[0];
    const bytes = ethers.encodeBytes32String(name);
    console.log('name: ',bytes)
}

createBytes(process.argv.slice(2));
```

```
name:  0x736f6d657468696e670000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

---

For more info, check the ['Utilities' documentation page](https://docs.ethers.org/v6/single-page/#migrating__migrate-utils)